# “rasa x" returns AttributeError

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-x

I have installed rasa x on my computer. `rasa shell` works well. I can chat within terminal. but when I try to run `rasa x` I get following error.I am using python 3.6 and tensorflow backend.

```
Starting Rasa X in local mode... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\rasaenv\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\rasaenv\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
EOFError: Ran out of input
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\rasaenv\lib\site-packages\rasa\cli\x.py", line 431, in run_locally
    args, project_path, args.data, token=rasa_x_token, config_path=config_path
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\rasaenv\lib\site-packages\rasax\community\local.py", line 186, in main
    app = rasa_x_server.configure_app()
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\rasaenv\lib\site-packages\rasax\community\api\app.py", line 206, in configure_app
    app.blueprint(interface.blueprint())
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\rasaenv\lib\site-packages\rasax\community\api\blueprints\interface.py", line 119, in blueprint
    interface_directory = locate_interface()
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\rasaenv\lib\site-packages\rasax\community\api\blueprints\interface.py", line 104, in locate_interface
    return build_interface()
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\rasaenv\lib\site-packages\rasax\community\api\blueprints\interface.py", line 80, in build_interface
    p.start()
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\rasaenv\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\rasaenv\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\rasaenv\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\rasaenv\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 65, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\rasaenv\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'build_interface.<locals>.run_build'

Sorry, something went wrong (see error above). Make sure to start Rasa X with valid data and valid domain and config files. Please, also check any warnings that popped up.
If you need help fixing the issue visit our forum: https://forum.rasa.com/.
```

All the packages are installed in a anaconda environment. I used pip to install rasa x . Here is what I did:

```
conda create -n rasaenv python=3.6
conda activate rasaenv
pip install rasa-x --extra-index-url https://pypi.rasa.com/simple
```

In my case `rasa init` command works. `rasa train` command works. But when I try `rasa x` command in comand promt , it doesn't works. It return `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'build_interface.<locals>.run_build'`

package installed in my environment:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
absl-py                   0.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
aiofiles                  0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
aiohttp                   3.6.2                    pypi_0    pypi
alembic                   1.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
apscheduler               3.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
astor                     0.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
async-generator           1.10                     pypi_0    pypi
async-timeout             3.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
attrs                     19.3.0                   pypi_0    pypi
boto3                     1.12.31                  pypi_0    pypi
botocore                  1.15.31                  pypi_0    pypi
cachetools                4.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2019.11.28               py36_1
cffi                      1.14.0                   pypi_0    pypi
chardet                   3.0.4                    pypi_0    pypi
cloudpickle               1.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
colorama                  0.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
colorclass                2.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
coloredlogs               10.0                     pypi_0    pypi
colorhash                 1.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
contextvars               2.4                      pypi_0    pypi
cryptography              2.8                      pypi_0    pypi
cycler                    0.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
decorator                 4.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
dnspython                 1.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
docopt                    0.6.2                    pypi_0    pypi
docutils                  0.15.2                   pypi_0    pypi
fbmessenger               6.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
future                    0.18.2                   pypi_0    pypi
gast                      0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
gevent                    1.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
gitdb                     4.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
gitpython                 3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
google-auth               1.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
google-pasta              0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
greenlet                  0.4.15                   pypi_0    pypi
grpcio                    1.27.2                   pypi_0    pypi
h11                       0.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
h2                        3.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
h5py                      2.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
hpack                     3.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
hstspreload               2020.3.25                pypi_0    pypi
httplib2                  0.17.0                   pypi_0    pypi
httptools                 0.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
httpx                     0.9.3                    pypi_0    pypi
humanfriendly             8.1                      pypi_0    pypi
hyperframe                5.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
idna                      2.9                      pypi_0    pypi
idna-ssl                  1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
immutables                0.11                     pypi_0    pypi
importlib-metadata        1.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
isodate                   0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jmespath                  0.9.5                    pypi_0    pypi
joblib                    0.14.1                   pypi_0    pypi
jsonpickle                1.3                      pypi_0    pypi
jsonschema                3.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
kafka-python              1.4.7                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-applications        1.0.8                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
kiwisolver                1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
mako                      1.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
markdown                  3.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib                3.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
mattermostwrapper         2.2                      pypi_0    pypi
multidict                 4.7.5                    pypi_0    pypi
networkx                  2.4                      pypi_0    pypi
numpy                     1.18.2                   pypi_0    pypi
oauth2client              4.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
oauthlib                  3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
opt-einsum                3.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
packaging                 19.0                     pypi_0    pypi
pika                      1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       20.0.2                   py36_1
prompt-toolkit            2.0.10                   pypi_0    pypi
protobuf                  3.11.3                   pypi_0    pypi
psycopg2-binary           2.8.4                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1                    0.4.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pycparser                 2.20                     pypi_0    pypi
pydot                     1.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyjwt                     1.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pykwalify                 1.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pymongo                   3.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyparsing                 2.4.6                    pypi_0    pypi
pyreadline                2.1                      pypi_0    pypi
pyrsistent                0.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pysocks                   1.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.6.10               h9f7ef89_1
python-crfsuite           0.9.7                    pypi_0    pypi
python-dateutil           2.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
python-editor             1.0.4                    pypi_0    pypi
python-engineio           3.11.2                   pypi_0    pypi
python-socketio           4.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
python-telegram-bot       11.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pytz                      2019.3                   pypi_0    pypi
pyyaml                    5.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
questionary               1.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
rasa                      1.9.3                    pypi_0    pypi
rasa-sdk                  1.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
rasa-x                    0.27.1                   pypi_0    pypi
redis                     3.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
requests                  2.23.0                   pypi_0    pypi
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
requests-toolbelt         0.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
rfc3986                   1.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
rocketchat-api            0.6.36                   pypi_0    pypi
rsa                       4.0                      pypi_0    pypi
ruamel-yaml               0.15.100                 pypi_0    pypi
s3transfer                0.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
sanic                     19.12.2                  pypi_0    pypi
sanic-cors                0.10.0.post3             pypi_0    pypi
sanic-jwt                 1.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
sanic-plugins-framework   0.9.2                    pypi_0    pypi
scikit-learn              0.22.2.post1             pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                46.1.1                   py36_0
six                       1.14.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sklearn-crfsuite          0.3.6                    pypi_0    pypi
slackclient               2.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
smmap                     3.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
sniffio                   1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
sqlalchemy                1.3.15                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.31.1               he774522_0
tabulate                  0.8.7                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard               2.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow                2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-addons         0.8.3                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-estimator      2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-hub            0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-probability    0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
terminaltables            3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tqdm                      4.31.1                   pypi_0    pypi
twilio                    6.26.3                   pypi_0    pypi
typeguard                 2.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
typing-extensions         3.7.4.1                  pypi_0    pypi
tzlocal                   2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ujson                     1.35                     pypi_0    pypi
urllib3                   1.25.8                   pypi_0    pypi
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_1
wcwidth                   0.1.9                    pypi_0    pypi
webexteamssdk             1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
websockets                8.1                      pypi_0    pypi
werkzeug                  1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.34.2                   py36_0
wincertstore              0.2              py36h7fe50ca_0
wrapt                     1.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
yarl                      1.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
zipp                      3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed in `rasa-x==0.27.3`. Running `pip install -U rasa-x --extra-index-url https://pypi.rasa.com/simple`now should get it working.

Comment: can you help on this https://forum.rasa.com/t/error-while-rasa-x-command/41707